# Derefrencing unique_ptr causes memory address to print infinitely

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr, dereference

The following code causes the memory address of "res" to print infinitely. I'm trying to dereference the "res" variable so it prints m_val. Do you know why it's printing infinitely?

```
class Resource
{
private:
    int m_val;
public:
    Resource(int val) { 
        m_val = val;
    }
    ~Resource() { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Resource &res)
    {
        out << &res << ": " << res << "\n";
        return out;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> res(new Resource(5));

    if (res) {
        std::cout << "*res: " << *res; //trying to dereference
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are other things I've tried to print instead of "*(&res)" in the print statement:

- *res - it says "illegal indirection"
- m_val - it says "illegal reference to non-static member 'Resource::m_val'"
- *&res - it loops infinitely with this too

Comment: Well your `<<` overload attempts to use `<<` with `res`, which is a `Resource`, so it must invoke the `<<` overload, i.e., itself. Obvious infinite recursion, so what exactly is your question? Perhaps you meant `val` instead of `res`, there.

Comment: ohh it's because i use << twice? i'm working through a tutorial on [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-5-stdunique_ptr/) and it overloads the operator using << one time. i didn't realize using it twice would cause an issue.

Comment: No, you can use `<<` a million times, if you're a patient typer. But if you attempt to use it in order to emit the same object it's being invoked for, you'll get infinite recursion.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks, i just started learning c++ a couple weeks ago, so i didn't realize that's what i was doing

Comment: It's like having a routine `int foo(int x) { return foo(x); }` ... which calls itself forever.  Or until the stack is exhausted.

Comment: maybe you meant `out << &res << ": " << res.m_val << "\n";`

Comment: @M.M thanks, that worked! plain old "m_val" would work in c#...haven't gotten the hang of c++ yet

Answer (score 2):

the following works, as per the comments above:

```
out << &res << ": " << res.m_val << "\n";
```